# Show that $u(t)=\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t-r}^{t+r}u(x)\,{\rm d}x=\frac{u(t-r)+u(t+r)}{2}$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, definite-integrals, proof-writing

Specifically, the question is as follows:

> Let $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$.
>
> a) Suppose a function $u:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of $u^{\prime\prime}(x) = 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$. Show that
>   $$
> u(t) = \frac{1}{2r} \int_{t-r}^{t+r} u(x) \, {\rm d} x = \frac{u(t-r) + u(t+r)}{2}
> $$
>    for every $t \in (a,b)$ and for every interval $(t-r, t+r) \subset (a,b)$ with $r>0$.
>
> b) Suppose a sufficiently smooth function $w:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
>   $$
> w(t) = \frac{1}{2r} \int_{t-r}^{t+r} w(x) \, {\rm d} x
> $$
>    for every $t \in (a,b)$ and for every interval $(t-r, t+r) \subset (a,b)$ with $r>0$.
>
> Show that 
>    $
> \displaystyle \frac{w(t-r) + w(t+r)}{2} = w(t)
>  $
>    and $w^{\prime\prime}(t) = 0$.

So, together, parts a) and b) make up an if and only if statement. My struggle is primarily with part a), but I'm also not entirely sure on part b).

For part a), I understand that $u''(x)=0$ tell us that $u$ is (at most) linear in $x$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from that assessment.

For part b), here is my proposed solution:

Observe that 
$$w(t-r)=\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t-2r}^tw(x)dx=\frac{w(t)-w(t-2r)}{2r}$$
and 
$$w(t+r)=\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t}^{t+2r}w(x)dx=\frac{w(t+2r)-w(t)}{2r}.$$
So
$$\frac{w(t-r)+w(t+r)}{2}=\frac{w(t+2r)-w(t-2r)}{4r}=\frac{1}{4r}\int_{t-2r}^{t+2r}w(x)dx.$$
Thus, without loss of generality, let $r=2r$, and the desired result follows. Then, by application of the Leibniz integral rule,
$$w'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t-r}^{t+r}w(x)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2r}\left[w(t+r)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(t+r)-w(t-r)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(t-r)+\int_{t-r}^{t+r}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}w(x)dx\right]$$

My questions here are specifically if I can simply let $r=2r$, or if I need to further justify that claim; and how do I handle $\int_{t-r}^{t+r}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}w(x)dx$ (or have I misunderstood the application of the Liebniz integral rule)?

Please note that this is a homework question, so I would prefer guidance to a full solution. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just put $u(x) = \alpha x + \beta$ and start to integrate?

Comment: @amsmath Oh, duh. Well that takes care of part a). Any suggestions on part b)?

Comment: Let $W$ be an anti-derivative of $w$. Then $w(t) = \tfrac1{2r}(W(t+r)-W(t-r))$ for all $t$ and all $r$. Now derive with respect to $r$.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you. I've posted a solution that I believe is correct, based on what you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Edit}$: This is incorrect (specifically part b). I'll leave it here in case others are tempted make the same error. A corrected version has been appended to the end to replace the section between the horizontal rules.

a) Because $u''(x)=0$, $u$ is linear in $x$. That is, $u(x)=\alpha x+\beta$, for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$\frac{u(t-r)+u(t+r)}{2}=\frac{\alpha(t-r)+\beta+\alpha(t-r)+\beta}{2}=\alpha t+\beta=u(t).$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t-r}^{t+r}\alpha x+\beta=\frac{1}{2r}\left[\frac{\alpha x^2}{2}\bigg\rvert_{t-r}^{t+r}+\beta x\bigg\rvert_{t-r}^{t+r}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2r}\left[\frac{\alpha(t+r)^2}{2}-\frac{\alpha(t-r)^2}{2}+\beta(t+r)-\beta(t-r)\right]=\frac{1}{2r}[2\alpha tr+2\beta r]=\alpha t+\beta=u(t).$$
The desired result follows.

b) Observe that 
$$w(t-r)=\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t-2r}^tw(x)dx=\frac{w(t)-w(t-2r)}{2r}$$
and 
$$w(t+r)=\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t}^{t+2r}w(x)dx=\frac{w(t+2r)-w(t)}{2r}.$$
So
$$\frac{w(t-r)+w(t+r)}{2}=\frac{w(t+2r)-w(t-2r)}{4r}=\frac{1}{4r}\int_{t-2r}^{t+2r}w(x)dx.$$
Thus, without loss of generality, let $r=2r$, and the desired result follows.

---

Then, let $W$ be the anti-derivative of $w$. Hence, by assumption, 
\begin{align}
\tag{*}
w(t)=\frac{1}{2r}(W(t+r)-W(t-r)).
\end{align}
Thus,
$$w'(t)=\frac{d}{dr}\left[\frac{1}{2r}(W(t+r)-W(t-r))\right].$$
By application of the product rule and the fact that the derivative of a difference is the difference of the derivatives, this evaluates to
$$\frac{1}{2r}(w(t+r)-w(t-r))-\frac{1}{2r^2}(W(t+r)-W(t-r)).$$
Then, since $\frac{w(t-r) + w(t+r)}{2} = w(t)$, this further reduces to 
$$\frac{w(t)}{r}-\frac{1}{2r^2}(W(t+r)-W(t-r)).$$
Applying $(*)$ to this, it follows that
$$w'(t)=\frac{1}{2r^2}(W(t+r)-W(t-r))-\frac{1}{2r^2}(W(t+r)-W(t-r))=0.$$
Therefore, $w''(t)=0$, as desired.

---

Then, applying the Leibniz integral rule,
$$w'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2r}\int_{t-r}^{t+r}w(x)dx\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2r}\left(w(t+r)\frac{d}{d t}(t+r)-w(t-r)\frac{d}{d t}(t-r)+\int_{t-r}^{t+r}\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}dx\right)=\frac{1}{2r}(w(t+r)-w(t-r)).$$
So,
$$w''(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(w'(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2r}(w(t+r)-w(t-r))\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2r}\left(\frac{1}{2r}(w(t+2r)-w(t))-\frac{1}{2r}(w(t)-w(t-2r))\right)$$
\begin{align}
\tag{$*$}
=\frac{1}{2r}\left(\frac{1}{2r}(w(t+2r)-w(t-2r))-\frac{1}{2r}(2w(t))\right).
\end{align}
Then, using the substitution $\frac{w(t-r) + w(t+r)}{2} = w(t)$, it follows that
$$(*)=\frac{1}{2r}\left(\frac{w(t)}{r}-\frac{w(t)}{r}\right)=0,$$
as desired.

Comment: Why is $\int_{t-2r}^tw(x)\,dx = w(t)-w(t-2r)$? In addition: When you derive (*) with respect to $t$, there is no product rule to use. The whole thing is much easier if you proceed the way I told you.

Comment: @amsmath Does the fundamental theorem of calculus not apply here? I see I did make a mistake and wrote $\frac{d}{dt}$ but then differentiated with respect to $r$, not $t$. But if this is not what you were indicating to do, then what is the idea?

Comment: There are several typos that you should correct.

Comment: @amsmath Aside from the $\frac{d}{dt}$ that I've corrected to be $\frac{d}{dr}$, what typos do I need to correct?

Comment: You should read your own stuff more accurately. There is a minus which should be a plus.

Comment: @amsmath So by "several", you mean that I have an error that I've carried forward? Or are there others as well? And could you help me find the flipped sign? I've read over my solution closely and I don't see it.